# Custom object as a DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I have a custom class, MyPerson. All (relevant) properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
I created a UserControl to display it, and it all worked fine. Binding to properties like MyPerson.FirstName (a string) all work - they display and update (two way binding) as expected.

Now I want to do more complex stuff in the codebehind, so I wanted to create a DependencyProperty with a PropertyType of MyPerson, but I'm not sure how to construct the DependencyProperty, in particular the PropertyChangedCallback part.

Can this be done? How so?

Comment: MSDN documentation shows this itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms753358.aspx If you scroll down to the section "Registering the property with the property system", it shows a custom DP being registered of type "AquariumObject" with a changed callback "OnUriChanged"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read on this article - [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties)

Something like -

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPersonValueProperty = 
      DependencyProperty.Register( "MyPersonValue", typeof(MyPerson), 
         typeof(MyPersonControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
               new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPersonChanged) ) ); 

public MyPerson ThePerson
{ 
    get { return (MyPerson)GetValue(MyPersonValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPersonValueProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnPersonChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                 DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Property change code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPersonValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "MyPersonValue",
          typeof(MyPerson),
          typeof(MyPersonControl),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
              new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriChanged)
          )
        ); and           public MyPerson ThePerson
        {
            get { return (MyPerson)GetValue(MyPersonValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyPersonValueProperty, value); }
        } was all I needed.

Comment: the problem with link-only answers...your link is dead

Comment: @Jonesy - Updated with some sample and updated the link as well. Thanks.